# Proof that doesn' t exists $f\in \mathcal{O}(\Theta)$ such that $\frac{df}{dz}=g(z)$, for all $z\in\Theta$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Theta=\{z\in \mathbb{C}\mid 1<|z|<2\}$ and complex function $g(z)=\frac{(e^{z}-z-1)^{9}}{(1-\cos{z})^{8}(e^{z}-1)^{3}}$.
Proof that doesn' t exists $f\in \mathcal{O}(\Theta)$ such that $\frac{df}{dz}=g(z)$, for all $z\in\Theta$.
We observe that $g$ has pole at $z=0$ with order 1.
My first thought was to use Residue Theorem, for proving that doesn't exist $f$,  but $\Theta$ is not a simply connected set. How can we proof this claim ?

Comment: if such $f$ would exist, what would be the integral of $g$ on the circle of radius $3/2$? What is in fact the above integral?

Comment: That was my first thought, to apply Residue Theorem on the circle $C(0,3/2)$. But, we khow that $\Theta$ isn't simply connected.

Comment: As Conrad hints at, think about the fundamental theorem of calculus for complex functions.

Comment: Not sure what simply connected has to do with anything for residues; the function is analytic on the punctured disc with radius $3/2$ so u can compute the circle integral using residues; on the other hand any derivative has zero circle integral so if u show the integral is non zero it follows that the function cannot be a derivative; in this case of an annulus which has fundamental group generated by that circle it is an if and only if (zero circle integral iff $g$ is a derivative)

Comment: Yes, i understood my fault. You're right. Thank you very much.